# Problem with the music player on the website - odd clicks

Tags: javascript, html, media-player, audio-player

I'm creating a music player for a website that will contain 14 playlists by default, but in the process of writing the site I've come across one problem - the selected playlist is only triggered by odd clicks on the page, any even clicks cause problems.

**In a nutshell:**

1. I click on playlist A with a single click - it works perfectly
2. Then I select playlist B with a single click - it does not work
3. Single click back to playlist A - works fine
4. Then I select playlist B with a double click - it works flawlessly

So every click #1, #3, #5, #7 etc works flawlessly, however clicks #2, #4, #6, #8 don't work, they don't play music and there is no way to pause or unpause the playlist either.

**Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RADIO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="buttons">
            <div class="button-L" onclick="document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/1.jpg)';"><button value="W" onclick="gra(this)">Playlista 1</button></div>
            <div class="button-S" onclick="document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/2.jpg)';"><button value="W1" onclick="gra(this)">Playlista 2</button></div>
            <div class="button-S" onclick="document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/3.jpg)';"><button value="W2" onclick="gra(this)">Playlista 3</button></div>
            <div class="button-S" onclick="document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/4.jpg)';"><button value="W3" onclick="gra(this)">Playlista 4</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
    <div class="music-container" id="music-container">
        <div class="music-info">
          <h4 id="title"></h4>
          <div class="progress-container" id="progress-container">
            <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
   
        <audio src="music/sport.mp3" id="audio"></audio>
   
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="img/cd-w3.jpg" alt="music-cover" id="cover">
        </div>
 
        <div class="navigation">
          <button id="prev" class="action-btn">
            <i class="fas fa-backward"></i>
          </button>
 
          <button id="play" class="action-btn action-btn-big">
            <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
          </button>
 
          <button id="next" class="action-btn">
            <i class="fas fa-forward"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function gra(tytul) {
            var tytulGry = tytul.value;
            var songs = [];
             
            // Song titles
            if(tytulGry === "W") songs = ['The Trail', 'Kaer Morhen'];
            else if(tytulGry === "W1") songs = ['After The Storm', 'Spikeroog'];
            else if(tytulGry === "W2") songs = ['Trauma', 'Foxkids'];
            else if(tytulGry === "W3") songs = ['Myspace', 'Sport'];
         
            const musicContainer = document.getElementById('music-container');
            const playBtn = document.getElementById('play');
            const prevBtn = document.getElementById('prev');
            const nextBtn = document.getElementById('next');
 
            const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
            const progress = document.getElementById('progress');
            const progressContainer = document.getElementById('progress-container');
            const title = document.getElementById('title');
            const cover = document.getElementById('cover');
            const currTime = document.querySelector('#currTime');
            const durTime = document.querySelector('#durTime')
             
            // Keep track of song
            let songIndex = 1;
 
            // Initially load song details into DOM
            loadSong(songs[songIndex]);
 
            // Update song details
            function loadSong(song) {
            title.innerText = song;
            audio.src = `music/`+song+`.mp3`;
            cover.src = `img/`+tytulGry+`.jpg`;
            }
 
            // Play song
            function playSong() {
            musicContainer.classList.add('play');
            playBtn.querySelector('i.fas').classList.remove('fa-play');
            playBtn.querySelector('i.fas').classList.add('fa-pause');
 
            audio.play();
            }
 
            // Pause song
            function pauseSong() {
            musicContainer.classList.remove('play');
            playBtn.querySelector('i.fas').classList.add('fa-play');
            playBtn.querySelector('i.fas').classList.remove('fa-pause');
 
            audio.pause();
            }
 
            // Previous song
            function prevSong() {
            songIndex--;
 
            if (songIndex < 0) {
                songIndex = songs.length - 1;
            }
 
            loadSong(songs[songIndex]);
 
            playSong();
            }
 
            // Next song
            function nextSong() {
            songIndex++;
 
            if (songIndex > songs.length - 1) {
                songIndex = 0;
            }
 
            loadSong(songs[songIndex]);
 
            playSong();
            }
 
            // Update progress bar
            function updateProgress(e) {
            const { duration, currentTime } = e.srcElement;
            const progressPercent = (currentTime / duration) * 100;
            progress.style.width = `${progressPercent}%`;
            }
 
            // Set progress bar
            function setProgress(e) {
            const width = this.clientWidth;
            const clickX = e.offsetX;
            const duration = audio.duration;
 
            audio.currentTime = (clickX / width) * duration;
            }
 
            //get duration & currentTime for Time of song
            function DurTime (e) {
                const {duration,currentTime} = e.srcElement;
                var sec;
                var sec_d;
 
                // define minutes currentTime
                let min = (currentTime==null)? 0:
                Math.floor(currentTime/60);
                min = min <10 ? '0'+min:min;
 
                // define seconds currentTime
                function get_sec (x) {
                    if(Math.floor(x) >= 60){
                         
                        for (var i = 1; i<=60; i++){
                            if(Math.floor(x)>=(60*i) && Math.floor(x)<(60*(i+1))) {
                                sec = Math.floor(x) - (60*i);
                                sec = sec <10 ? '0'+sec:sec;
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        sec = Math.floor(x);
                        sec = sec <10 ? '0'+sec:sec;
                    }
                } 
 
                get_sec (currentTime,sec);
 
                // change currentTime DOM
                currTime.innerHTML = min +':'+ sec;
 
                // define minutes duration
                let min_d = (isNaN(duration) === true)? '0':
                    Math.floor(duration/60);
                min_d = min_d <10 ? '0'+min_d:min_d;
 
 
                function get_sec_d (x) {
                    if(Math.floor(x) >= 60){
                         
                        for (var i = 1; i<=60; i++){
                            if(Math.floor(x)>=(60*i) && Math.floor(x)<(60*(i+1))) {
                                sec_d = Math.floor(x) - (60*i);
                                sec_d = sec_d <10 ? '0'+sec_d:sec_d;
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        sec_d = (isNaN(duration) === true)? '0':
                        Math.floor(x);
                        sec_d = sec_d <10 ? '0'+sec_d:sec_d;
                    }
                } 
 
                // define seconds duration
                 
                get_sec_d (duration);
 
                // change duration DOM
                durTime.innerHTML = min_d +':'+ sec_d;
                     
            };
 
            // Event listeners
            playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const isPlaying = musicContainer.classList.contains('play');
 
            if (isPlaying) {
                pauseSong();
            } else {
                playSong();
            }
            });
 
            // Change song
            prevBtn.addEventListener('click', prevSong);
            nextBtn.addEventListener('click', nextSong);
 
            // Time/song update
            audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgress);
 
            // Click on progress bar
            progressContainer.addEventListener('click', setProgress);
 
            // Song ends
            audio.addEventListener('ended', nextSong);
 
            // Time of song
            audio.addEventListener('timeupdate',DurTime);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The songs are .mp3 files whose names are stored in the variable songs[]; Where is the source of the problem?